# Darken Video Background

Tags: html, css

How to Darken Background in a video without affecting the text over it?

```
 <div class="fullscreen-bg">   
    <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
        <source src="images/instituteVideo.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
    <div class="text-vid">
        <h2 class="texts">Transform into a Smart Institute</h2>
    </div>
</div>

.fullscreen-bg {    
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            height: 84vh;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            object-fit: cover;
            z-index: -99;
            position: relative;
            filter: brightness(75%);
    }

    .text-vid {
            position: absolute;
            top:10%;
     }
```

This is what i have tried , i have also tried using background-color which doesn't work. Using filter darkens the background , but also affects the text color

Comment: There is no way to that by any means, you can't alter a video by CSS or jQuery. Why dont you try to make video like you want or just use plain background video and make text animation on it using HTML and CSS animation.

Comment: ruchika, you mean the div background or the video overlay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use an absolutely-positioned pseudo element that is placed over the video, but underneath your text:

```
.fullscreen-bg::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: '';

    /* Any overlay color that you want, here I use black with 25% opacity */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
```

Comment: I need to add z-index: 200 here to work

Answer (score 21):

Simply add this-

```
video {
   filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

Comment: Easy and simple...

Comment: Also darkens any text sitting in the div, which is the most likely situation. So not a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

```css
:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(
    180deg, 
    rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%,
    rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 100%
    ),
    linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%, transparent 100%);
    z-index: 2;
}
```